# SQL Server 2008: Unique constraint for values non-related with columns

Tags: sql-server, constraints, unique

I have a simple problem. How can I add a unique constraint for a table, without relating the values to their columns? For example, I have this table

```
ID_A  ID_B
----------
  1    2
 ...  ...
```

In that example, I have the record (1,2). For me, (1,2) = (2,1). So i don't want to allow my database to store both values. I know I can accomplish it using, triggers or checks and functions. But i was wondering if there is any instruccion like

```
CREATE UNIQUE CONSTRAINT AS A SET_CONSTRAINT
```

Comment: Is it just two columns? You can enforce that with an indexed view. Are the columns unique individually as well?

Comment: Yes, it is just two columns. I have a table, only with these columns. Both are foreign keys to the same table, and both are primary keys. So the columns are not unique by themselves. For example i could have this records (1,2),(1,3),(2,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a view like that:

```
select 1 as Dummy
from T t1
join T t2 on t1.ID1 = t2.ID2 AND t1.ID2 = t2.ID1 --join to corresponding row
cross join TwoRows
```

And create a unique index on `Dummy`. `TwoRows` is a table that contains two rows with arbitrary contents. It is supposed to make the unique index fail if there ever is a row in it. Any row in this view indicates a uniqueness violation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It could be a really quick way to accomplish my requirements, without to write the triggers to insert and update.

Comment: Wow I never considered that. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `Instead of Insert` trigger.

### Demo

**Table Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE te(ID_A INT,ID_B INT)

INSERT te VALUES ( 1,2)
```

**Trigger**

```
Go
CREATE TRIGGER trg_name
ON te
instead OF INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM   inserted a
                 WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM   te b
                                WHERE  ( ( a.id_a = b.id_b
                                           AND a.id_b = b.id_a )
                                          OR ( a.id_a = b.id_a
                                               AND a.id_b = b.id_b ) )))
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'duplciate record'
            ROLLBACK
        END
      ELSE
        INSERT INTO te
        SELECT Id_a,id_b
        FROM   inserted
  END

SELECT * FROM   te
```

**Insert Script**

```
INSERT INTO te VALUES (2,1) -- Duplicate

INSERT INTO te VALUES (1,2) --Duplicate

INSERT INTO te VALUES (3,2) --Will work
```

Comment: what is inserted  table i didnt get you

Comment: @koushikveldanda - May be this should help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms191300.aspx

Comment: @NoDisplayName thanks for the comment. This is the solution i was developing when the upper question got to my mind. I thought it might be a quicker way, for example, treating the rows in an unique constraint like a set.

Comment: @Rumpel - What are you trying to mean here? I didn't get you

Comment: @NoDisplayName Don't worry, it's probably my english. When I talk about treating the rows like a set, i mean a math set: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)  If you set an unique constraint, and you try to insert this record (1,2). The database will check if there is not other column with ID_A=1 and ID_B=2. But I was wondering, if there is any way to check also that there is no other column with ID_A=2 and ID_B=1. In  maths, when you define a set, {1,2} = {2,1}. As i say, i know how to accomplish it using triggers, but i thought, there might be a way to do it by default. I see i was wrong